Compare coefficients across different regressions in R
I would like to test if the coefficients across different regressions are the same in R and I am not sure how I should do it.
Let me illustrate. I have an independent variable of interest called treat
I want to see if the treatment has the same effect on two different outcomes y1 and y2.
How can I do it?
Assume I have a dataset that looks like this.
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Create example dataset
n <- 500  # Number of observations
groups <- 20  # Number of groups
years <- 10  # Number of years

# Simulate group and year identifiers
group <- rep(1:groups, each = n / groups)
yr <- rep(1:years, length.out = n)

# Simulate treatment assignment
treat <- sample(c(0, 1), size = n, replace = TRUE)

# Create covariates and treatment effects
X <- rnorm(n)  # Random covariate
epsilon1 <- rnorm(n, sd = 2)  # Error term for Y1
epsilon2 <- rnorm(n, sd = 2)  # Error term for Y2

# Generate dependent variables
Y1 <- 5 + 2 * treat + 0.5 * X + epsilon1  # Y1: treatment effect = 2
Y2 <- 5 + 1 * treat + 0.5 * X + epsilon2  # Y2: treatment effect = 1

# Combine into a data frame
dt <- data.frame(group, yr, treat, X, Y1, Y2)

My objective is to evaluate if treat has a significantly different effect on Y1 relative to Y2.
I hence estimate my two models. In this case I am using two way fixed effects.
# Estimate the model for Y1
twfe_Y1 <- feols(Y1 ~ i(treat, ref = FALSE) | yr + group, data = dt, vcov = ~group)

# Estimate the model for Y2
twfe_Y2 <- feols(Y2 ~ i(treat, ref = FALSE) | yr + group, data = dt, vcov = ~group)

I can then compare models using etable
etable(twfe_Y1,twfe_Y2)
                  twfe_Y1           twfe_Y2
Dependent Var.:                Y1                Y2
                                                   
treat = 1       2.079*** (0.2368) 1.062*** (0.1361)
Fixed-Effects:  ----------------- -----------------
yr                            Yes               Yes
group                         Yes               Yes
_______________ _________________ _________________
S.E.: Clustered         by: group         by: group
Observations                  500               500
R2                        0.22430           0.11058
Within R2                 0.19325           0.05948
---
Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

How can I test if the coefficient of treat on Y1 is significantly different from the coefficient on Y2?
Note that I cannot stack the Ys and estimate a model with the interaction between treatment and Y group, because in the real analysis I am using some of the new Difference in differences packages for the estimation process and it is not entirely clear how they can include interaction with the treatment.
So I need a method that ex post takes coefficients & standard errors and test for equality of coefficient.
Any guidance on how to implement this would be great.

Please let us know what package(s) you are using, and ideally provide some sample data so we can run the code. I am not familiar with feols and etable so I don't know exactly what they're doing.

may you want to explain want to explain  "compare equality of coefficient". you just could get coefficients and se by coef(m1) coef(m2) and/ or se(m1) se(m2) but I gues you dont want that?

This may be relevant: https://github.com/kylebutts/vcovSUR

Dear all. I have created some example data. If anyone know how to do it in practice it would be amazing

Have you even looked at the link I posted? It does exactly what you are asking for.

As Vincent suggested,  github.com/kylebutts/vcovSUR  should give you exactly what you need.
Here is how to do it with your example
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kylebutts/vcovSUR")
library(fixest)
library(vcovSUR)

sur_hypotheses(
  list(twfe_Y1, twfe_Y2), cluster = "rowid",
  hypothesis = "`treat::1_1`  = `treat::1_2`" # mind the quotes!
)

 Estimate Std. Error   z Pr(>|z|)    S 2.5 % 97.5 %
     1.02      0.261 3.9   <0.001 13.3 0.506   1.53

I was also reading a very similar topic here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions, and it was suggested to use a Z statistic, which I think can be calculated as follows
beta1 <- as.numeric(twfe_Y1$coefficients)
se1<- as.numeric(twfe_Y1$se)
beta2 <- as.numeric(twfe_Y2$coefficients)
se2<- as.numeric(twfe_Y2$se)

Z <- (beta1 - beta2)/ sqrt(se1^2 + se2^2)

I did not dive deep into it, but I noted that, interestingly, these two methods return very similar (but not identical) p-values
pnorm(Z, lower.tail = F)

9.784923e-05

sur_hypotheses(
     list(twfe_Y1, twfe_Y2), cluster = "rowid",
     hypothesis = "`treat::1_1`  = `treat::1_2`" 
   )$p.value

9.743827e-05


One thing: do you also have indication of some paper that describes the approach of vcovSUR and why it is fit for my task? thanks a lot

You're welcome!  I do not have any indications about papers unfortunately, but you can still have a look at the links posted above (something might be there, not sure), or even ask directly to the creator of the package via Github

I was playing with my real data, and I get an error. do you know what it may be? here is my code sur_hypotheses(
list(twfe_Y1, twfe_Y2), cluster = "rowid",
hypothesis = "post_trai182::1_1  = post_trai182::1_2" # mind the quotes!
) and the error is Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': subscript out of bounds
